# C# avoid SQL Injection in a function

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I want to create a class that help SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE and DELETE in SQL server databases , but I've found by search that there is "sql injection" and the way to avoid it is to use a function like the following :

```
private static void Select() {
    string cmdStr = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Telephone FROM Person WHERE FirstName = @FirstName";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, connection)) {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "John");
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) {
            string output = "First Name: {0} \t Last Name: {1} \t Phone: {2}";
            Console.WriteLine(output, reader["FirstName"], reader["LastName"], reader["Telephone"]);
        }
    }
}
```

does the following function can have sql injection ?

```
  private static void SelectWithWhere(String query, String[] parameters)
        {

            {
                string cmdStr = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Telephone FROM Person WHERE "+parameters[0];
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", parameters[0]);
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string output = "First Name: {0} \t Last Name: {1} \t Phone: {2}";
                        Console.WriteLine(output, reader["FirstName"], reader["LastName"], reader["Telephone"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The first function? No. The second function? Yes.

Comment: thank you for the answer , this means I can't create a class with function that can select , update , I must every time write different version of the first function (depend on parameters that it takes) @canon

Comment: User entered data going to the database should (very nearly) always go through SQL parameters.  Unless you have an excessively good reason (and probably not even then), do not in-line user entered values into your query.  It is more OK to use user entered values to change flow, since you won't execute arbitrary code that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you use an input provided by a user to generate an SQL statement, you open the door to SQL injection.  The **only** way to avoid sql injection is by using parameters.

The first function is safe but the second one may be vulnerable to sql injection if you don't control the provided `String[] parameters`.  If the user is providing the value for this array (directly or indirectly), he could pass an sql statement of it's own an execute basically anything he wants on your database.

Comment: please is there sql injection danger if I use : ` string cmdStr = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Telephone FROM Person WHERE FirstName = @FirstName";` in the second function & command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", parameters[0]); ?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you use `SqlParameter` to add the user input into the query, you're safe of Sql Injection.

If you use string concatenations, you need to parse the user input to ensure you're not issuing a malicious query.

Honestly, and *outside of the scope of this question*, nowadays is very outdated to write Ado.Net code directly. There are tons of micro-Orms that will easy up your life.

Answer (score 1):

The function above no, because you are passing the value as a `SqlArgument`. rather than as part of your SQL. The second method, yes, if parameters were to contain something like this:

```
parameters = new [] { "1<>1;DROP TABLE PERSON;" }
```

your query to execute would end up being:

```
"SELECT FirstName, LastName, Telephone FROM Person WHERE 1<>1;DROP TABLE PERSON;"
```

Which SQL Server would execute first statement (`SELECT`) followed by the second statement `DROP`

Comment: thank you for the answer , is there a way to secure the second function because I'll have so much select statement to do and I'll have so much code duplicated ?

Comment: It is very unlikely that the user is entering the text of the where clause directly.  Instead of concatenating down to that, figure out what fields they're querying on, build dynamic SQL that uses parameters, and then populate the parameters.